# Check if element is present in viewport with NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-hooks, scroll, viewport

I'm trying to create a scrollspy from scratch with Material UI in my NextJS project.

I'd like the `navigationValue` state to change each time designated elements are visible on page (classic scrollspy behavior).

```js
function isInViewport(element: any) {
    const _el = document.querySelector(`${element}`)

    const rect = _el?.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (rect) {
        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        );
    } else return false
}

export default function Scrollspy(props: any) {

    const [navigationValue, setNavigationValue] = React.useState<string>('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck)
    }, [])

    const anchors = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D"
    ]

    const scrollCheck = () => {
        anchors.forEach((anchor: any) => {
            if (isInViewport(`#${anchor}`)) {
                setNavigationValue(anchor)
            }
        })
    }
}

// ... component and scrollspy menu
```

By now, scrolling effectively trigger the `isInVIewport` hook and `rect` is always neither null nor undefined, but the return condition always returns `false`.

Note that the `isInVIewport` hook is a copy of an already existing answer for this kind of issue (react only), but wasn't made by me, so I don't know how to properly tweak it at this point.

How should I do?